# Cannot install IBM WebSphere MQ Explorer into Eclipse Luna SR2 (4.4.2)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ibm-mq

I am running into an error when trying to download IBM Websphere MQ Explorer with the Eclipse Marketplace.  The error reads:
        "An error occurred while installing the items
        session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null -->[R]com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc 8.0.0.201506171824, action=).
        Failed to prepare partial IU: [R]com.ibm.mq.explorer.doc 8.0.0.201506171824."

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't seen this error before and I don't normally dig into the guts of Eclipse so I do not have a good feel for what might be going wrong.  But after some searching, I see this seems to be a fairly common error and I found a forum thread with a workaround.  The solution has a lot of confirmation messages following it from people with a wide variety of modules who were able to complete their installs.  Perhaps it will work for you.

I'll quote the relevant bits and provide [this link](https://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/issues/detail?id=47) to the source thread.

> So, go to Help -> Install New Software..., choose "The Eclipse Project
>   Updates - http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4" from the
>   "Work with" list and then in the "Eclipse Tests, Examples, and Extras"
>   category check "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support" and install it.
>   After restarting Eclipse, install veloeclipse again and this time the
>   installation will succeed.

Comment: T.Rob, thank you for your answer.  I downloaded "Eclipse 2.0 Style Plugin Support" at the directory you mentioned and I was able to download "IBM Websphere MQ Explorer" without running into the installation error.